# Expo BarcodeScanner via Camera returning wrong bounds

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been attempting to utilize the barcode scanner via the Camera exported by `expo-camera` due to being able to freeze the scanner upon scanning a valid QRCode. The problem is, the bounds being returned for the scanned region are incorrect.

Here is my usage of the Camera component:

```
<Camera
  flashMode={flashMode}
  barCodeTypes={[BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]}
  onBarCodeScanned={scannedRegion ? undefined : handleQRScanned}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }}
  ref={(el) => setScanner(el)}
>
```

The `handleQRScanned` method is just logging the output.

And here is what the scanned object looks like:

```
{
  "bounds": Object {
    "origin": Object {
      "x": 0.7085477709770203,
      "y": 0.2856549024581909,
    },
    "size": Object {
      "height": 0.41216737031936646,
      "width": 0.23583674430847168,
    },
  },
  "cornerPoints": Array [
    Object {
      "x": 0.7085477791037765,
      "y": 0.6859185008442614,
    },
    Object {
      "x": 0.9367770043059619,
      "y": 0.69782228348775,
    },
    Object {
      "x": 0.9443845063336068,
      "y": 0.29520473921943935,
    },
    Object {
      "x": 0.7161692883258375,
      "y": 0.28565489300913066,
    },
  ],
  "data": "exp://192.168.1.4:19000",
  "target": 5303,
  "type": "org.iso.QRCode",
}
```

Also, when previously using the `BarcodeScanner` exported by `expo-barcode-scanner` directly, the bounds come out correct. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved it by multiplying bound values with screen height and width from Dimensions API. By this way, you can correctly localize barcodes in screen. Here is the code snippet. Height and width are inversely proportioned meaning that bounds.size.width actually corresponds to screen height and vice versa.

```
height: Number(bounds.size.width) * deviceHeight,
width: Number(bounds.size.height) * deviceWidth, 
right: Number(bounds.origin.y) * deviceWidth,
top: Number(bounds.origin.x) * deviceHeight,
```

Comment: I was pulling my hairs out why I couldn't get it to work. Switching the height and width, and the x and y coordinates did the trick. Thanks!